# adding shadow elevation around the text field

Tags: flutter, dart

is there any way to add shadow around the text field, not just bottom text field with elevation property.

```
Material(
  elevation: 5.0,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintStyle: robotoRegular.copyWith(fontSize: Dimensions.fontSizeSmall, color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),),
      prefixIcon: IconButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        onPressed: widget.iconPressed as void Function()?,
        icon: Icon(widget.suffixIcon, color: widget.filledColor, size: 25,),
          // color: widget.iconColor ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.color
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@The Code Whisperer Just wrap the `TextField` in a Container and apply a `BoxDecoration` with a `boxShadow`.

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              spreadRadius: 3,
              blurRadius: 5,
              offset: Offset(0, 3))
        ],
      ),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        ),
      )
    );
```

Hopefully, this is useful!

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any more questions or need further assistance, feel free to ask. I'm here to help!

Comment: You're my man, this is so lovely, can I get your social media account?

Comment: You can visit our website at webdesksolution.com to find all the information you need.